# Managed EWS - Reply Post with alternative From property

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api, public-folders

In managed Exchange Web Services there is a class [PostItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.postitem_members(v=EXCHG.80).aspx), which can be instantiate with ExchangeService object.

But after assigning all properties including with *InReplyId* and From, and calling Save(folderId) method:

```
        PostItem newPost = new PostItem(mService);
        newPost.InReplyTo = originalPost.Id.UniqueId;
        newPost.From = new EmailAddress( "Max Gontar", "mgontar@server.com" );
        newPost.Subject = msg.Subj;
        newPost.Body = msg.TextBody;
        newPost.Save(mCurrentFolderId);
```

It still creates a separate Post, not a Reply Post:

Other way I have tried:

```
        PostReply reply = originalPost.CreatePostReply();
        reply.Subject = msg.Subj;
        reply.Body = msg.TextBody;
        reply.Save( currentFolder.Id )
```

There is no way to set From property, so it should create Post Reply with current credentials Contact email address. *But it gives null there!*

[image]

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Im just learning about this api but this code may work:

```
 newpost.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I'll test and let you know result!